# Displaying a list of images using AJAX in Codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

### Introduction:

I have a database which stores a list of file names, these file names correspond to an image in the folder user_data.

**My Codeigniter directory structure look like so:**

```
-application
-system
-assets
-user_data
```

**and the database like so:**

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
```

---

### What I'm trying to achieve:

I want to asynchronously using Ajax get all the file names in the database and then use the file names to display all the images in a little gallery. It's important that this is done without any page refresh.

---

### My code so far:

**Controller**

```
class Create extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('create', $data);
    }

}
```

**View**

```
<div id='gallery'> <!-- images will be displayed in here -->                

</div>

<!-- gallery should be updated when submit is clicked -->
<button id="update">Click to load images</button>
```

What I want is for all the images represented in the database to be displayed in the gallery when the user clicks on update.

How should I start to build a JS function to handle this? I want to perform this and respect the MVC pattern.

I'm new to Codeigniter and MVC and am not sure how to correctly build a model and controller to do this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't got time to write it all out but something like this should work:

```
class Create extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('files');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('create', $data);
    }

    public function get_files()
    {
        echo json_encode($this->files->get_files());
    }
}

class Files extends CI_Model
{
    public function get_files()
    {
        return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM files")->result_array();
    }
}


$(document).ready(function()
    $('#update').on('click',function(){
       $.ajax({
          url:'/create/get_files',
          type:'GET',
          success:function(result){
             var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

            // Loop through 'data' and append to the DOM

          }
       })
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this when I get home and give an update of how it went.

Answer (score 1):

Try This on your `view page`:

But first add `jquery` in your `header file` or in `your view`

**PHP**

```
<?php
class Model_name extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /* Model code */
    function get_image_list(){
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM <table>");
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
       return $query->result();
    }
 }

/*  Controller Code */

function update_gallery()
{
    $this->load->model('Model_name');
    $result = $this->Model_name->get_image_list();
    $str='';
    foreach($result as $row){
        $str.='<img src="'.$row['filepath'].'" alt="'.$row['title'].'" />';
    }
    echo $str;  
}

?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function()
    $('#update').on('click',function(){
       $.ajax({
          url:'yourpagecontroller',
          type:'GET',
          success:function(data){
          // let data comes like: <img src="path.jpg" alt="Name of image" /><img .../>, etc
             $('#gallery').html(data);
          }
       })
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I build the controller for this? Should I make a new function in my Create controller, for example called 'public function update_gallery()' then in the ajax url call create/update_gallery ?

Comment: You can get `json` from `controller` and then `traverse` it in `ajax jquery success callback function`.